# What is the best free program to burn DVD movies from DVD movie files that are present on the hard drive the way ImgBurn does it in Windows?

Tags: iso, burning

Evaluating burning programs is difficult: it takes more time to find how things really are, and meanwhile the errors are very unpleasant. Also, a lot of people, in Linux as well as in Windows, seem to take it very lightly when evaluating burning software. I have read  along the years a lot of good comments on all sort of Windows programs that after a while prove not to worth trying - at the expense of my time, lost data and nerves. Burning software is good until it is proved otherwise, which usually doesn't take to long. They should be discussed against reliable benchmarks set by well confirmed software: Nero, and lately ImgBurn (and maybe also CDBurnerXP) in Windows.

I have looked at **AcetoneISO, Brasero, and K3B** (which many recommend) but they seem more limited than the mentioned Windows apps. They are all said to work, but then at a more basic level (create ISO, burn them, etc.). When it comes to something like creating a DVD movie disk from DVD movie files present on the hard drive, it seems to me that I would have to firstly create the ISO and then burn it, which involves using more hard drive space and more time.

My own experience with the most recommended Ubuntu burning software (k3b, k9copy) was bad. (Could it be related to their k-related condition and my Xfce DE?)

One is not bound to give a **second** try to one peace of software that crashes or gives an unreadable disk the **first** time. In Ubuntu the situation on the matter is for now similar to that in Windows of some years ago when Nero ruled unrivaled. Until came **ImgBurn** - which, yes, **works** in **Wine**.

(There is a **Nero 4 for Linux**. It costs money. The sweetest taboo.)

What other options are there?

(I am in Xubuntu 11.10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using K9copy, and I love it.

> k9copy provides the following features:
>
> - The video stream can be compressed to make the video fit on any    configurable target size
> - DVD Burning
> - Transcode DVD using mencoder or ffmpeg with configurable presets
> - Creation of ISO images
> - The possibility of choosing which audio and subtitle tracks to copy
> - Title preview (video only)
> - The ability to preserve the original menus <sup>1</sup>

You can get it at the USC

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/k9copy/)</sup>

[image]

Another option to create a DVD movie disk from DVD movie files present on the hard drive, Use Bombono

[image]

Bombono DVD is easy to use program for making DVD-Video. The main features of Bombono DVD are:

- excellent MPEG viewer: Timeline and Monitor
- real WYSIWYG Menu Editor with live thumbnails
- comfortable Drag-N-Drop support
- you can author to folder, make ISO-image or burn directly to DVD
- reauthoring: you can import video from DVD discs. <sup>2</sup>

<sup><sup>**2**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps Directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bombono-dvd/)</sup>

Comment: Actually, I used K9copy yesterday, about 5 or six times, with no problems.  I'm running 12.04, what release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: hi! are you still using k9copy in latest ubuntus? not available for 14.04 from the sources I see

Comment: I still do on my 12.04 machine, but on 14.04 I'm using DVD95, and DeVeDe.  You can try to build from source k9copy, I haven't tried it, but you can take a look at [this](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?64493-k9copy-fans).

Comment: with DVD95 I copied 2 dvds yesterday, and saved as iso. but the isos are not usable as they should. normally a dvd movie saved as iso can be opened in vlc. not the ones that i got, they crash vlc, even playing the video folder crashes it. smplayer can play the videos from the folder but one by one without the dvd movie structure. can devede save the structure as dvdshrink does?